# Why log4net do not log from finalize method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, log4net

I did not found any document and any question about why log4net do not work in `Finalize` method.
I made this small example showing the problem:

```
Class LoggerTest

    Private ReadOnly logger As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(New System.IO.FileInfo("LoggerTest.log4net"))

        Dim c As New LoggerTest
        c.SayHello()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SayHello()
        System.Console.WriteLine("hello")
        logger.Info("hello")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        System.Console.WriteLine("finalize")
        logger.Info("finalize")
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the log4net fconfig file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
      <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

after execution of the code above I obtain the following results in my console:

```
hello
2020-04-07 12:36:24,678 [1] INFO  - hello
finalize
```

Do you know if is it normal? Is it possible to use log4net inside `Finalize` method?

Comment: It is normal, finalization order is not predictable.  So if the logger gets destroyed before the LoggerClass object then you can't see anything.  First guidance is to never write a Finalize() method, second is to never do anything risky when you have to anyway.  You don't have to.

Comment: I want to monitor objects which are destroyed but not closed by calling Close method. In my case when I put a breakpoint I see that "c" object is not null. I have same result if I change line code orders in Finalize method. How can I log the event elseway?

Comment: Of course this info belongs in the question.

Comment: It works when I call again `XmlConfigurator.Configure` method. It could be ok for stand-alone application, but for server application I don't know how to handle it. The configuration is automatically loaded from `web.config` file

Answer (score 0):

"Finally" I have found why there was no logging. The finalize method was called after the end of main program. If `Finalise` is called when the main program is running, log4net works. See example below.

```
Module LoggerTest
    Private ReadOnly logger As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)

    Public Sub Main()
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(New System.IO.FileInfo("LoggerTest.log4net"))

        Dim c As New HelloTest
        c.SayHello()
        c = Nothing
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        logger.Info("Goodbye")
    End Sub
End Module

Class HelloTest
    Private Shared ReadOnly logger As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)

    Public Sub SayHello()
        System.Console.WriteLine("hello")
        logger.Info("hello")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        logger.Info("finalize")
        System.Console.WriteLine("finalize")
    End Sub
End Class
```

After execution I obtain the following results:

```
hello
2020-04-08 09:48:20,137 [LoggerTest.HelloTest] INFO  - hello
2020-04-08 09:48:20,153 [LoggerTest.HelloTest] INFO  - finalize
finalize
2020-04-08 09:48:22,169 [LoggerTest.LoggerTest] INFO  - Goodbye
```